# LINQ - Is Where(Predicate).FirstOrDefault() the same as FirstOrDefault(Predicate)

Tags: linq

I have always written my LINQ queries with the predicate in the Where clause followed by the FirstOrDefault clause. I started seeing examples with the predicate in the FirstOrDefault clause.

Is one better than the other? Would the answer be different with EF (SQL)?

A. Using Where Clause

```
List<Product> products = GetProductList(); 

Product productWhere = products.Where(p => p.ProductID == 789).FirstOrDefault();
```

B. No Where Clause

```
List<Product> products = GetProductList(); 

Product productNoWhere = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == 789);
```

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Element-Operators-0f3f12ce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because method chains in Linq are lazily evaluated, there shouldn't be any material difference between the two.  `Where.FirstOrDefault` will stop executing when it obtains a value, just as `FirstOrDefault(Predicate)` will.

To put it another way, `FirstOrDefault` (or any other Linq operator downstream, for that matter) accepts items *one at a time* from `Where` for evaluation, not the entire list at once (The result of a Linq operator that returns an `IEnumerable` is essentially a `yield` `return` under the hood).

**See Also**
[Where.FirstOrDefault vs FirstOrDefault](https://web.archive.org/web/20141016045342/https://prashantvc.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/where-firstordefault-vs-firstordefault/)

Comment: I have found instances where they behave differenty.  Without the WHERE clause you can get unexpected results.